# Cannot create new line using "\n".join in python

Tags: python

For the following code

```
def add_empty_line(input_str):
    lines = input_str.split('\n')
    if lines[0] != '':
        lines.insert(0, '')

    print('before', lines)

    join_lines = '\n'.join(lines)

    print('after', join_lines)

    return join_lines

add_empty_line('test')
```

I got

```
before ['', 'test']
after
test
```

I expect to get an empty line before the `test` in the outpu. Why it does not work in this way?

I tried to use another approach,

```
a = ['', 'test']
b = '\n'.join(a)
print(b)
```

and got an empty line in front.

Comment: There is a `\n` after the word `after` inside the function. If you use print(add_empty_line('test')), you will see the newline...

Comment: Thanks! At least this solves my problem in the question. It comes from a bigger code, which I need to look into.